# How to create aws_instance without ebs_block_device?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Im trying to create an EC2 instance without any additional `ebs_block_device`. I just need a `root_block_device`. It would appear the default behavior for `ebs_block_device` when no config is provided, is to create a 2048 GB volume. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Below is the `aws_instance` resource for your reference. I have tried setting `volume_size` to 0 which didn't trigger any errors but still created the default 2048 GB volume.

```
 resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
   ami = data.my_ami.id
   instance_type = "t3.small" 

   root_block_device {
     volume_size = 20
   }
   tags = {
     Name = "my-ec2-host"
   }
 }
```

**Update:** I have understood that the additional 2048 `ebs_block_device` is default due to the AMI I am using. However is there any way to override this default (like I can from the UI)?

Comment: What is your AMI id?

Comment: As @Marcin hints at this is almost certainly because your AMI has a secondary disk. AFAIK there's no way to override having that extra disk so you should create a new AMI or use a different one without that extra disk. Also see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html#process-creating-an-ami-ebs

Comment: yup this is absolutely the case. I created a new AMI without the extra disk and was able to confirm that no additional disk was adding when creating instances from this AMI